# Ajax Array to PHP issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

Im having difficulties when parsing an array using Ajax to PHP to send an email with the values from the array.

Ajax code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#submit-button").click(function(){

                var countryArray = ['Location Zero', 'Location One', 'Location Two'];

                dataString = countryArray; 
                var jsonString = JSON.stringify(dataString);

                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "sendmail.php",
                        data: {countries: jsonString},
                        success: function (msg) {

                            $("#errors").text("Thank you for getting in touch, we will get back to you!");

                        },
                        error: function (msg) {
                            $("#errors").text("Error sending email, please try again.");

                            alert("error");
                        }
                    });


});

});
```

PHP code:

```
<?php


        $to = "abc@abc.com";
        $countries = json_decode($_POST['countries']);

        $header = "Content-Type: text/html\r\nReply-To: \r\nFrom:  <>";
        $subject = "Email from the Lister customer";

        $body = @"$countries";


        if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)) {
            die("true");    
        } else {
            die("There was an error sending the email.");   
        }


?>
```

But all I'm getting with in the email from `$countries` is word "Array" instead of the values.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: `$countries` is an array so use `implode(", ", $countries);` to print it as a string.

Comment: `@"$countries"`? don't suppress errors, and don't use cargo-cult programming...

Comment: thanks you guys, that all works perfectly now :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Implode array values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854520/php-implode-array-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php


    $to = "abc@abc.com";
    $countries = json_decode($_POST['countries']);

    $header = "Content-Type: text/html\r\nReply-To: \r\nFrom:  <>";
    $subject = "Email from the Lister customer";

    $body = implode(", ", $countries);


    if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)) {
        die("true");    
    } else {
        die("There was an error sending the email.");   
    }
?>
```

Comment: @YogeshSuthar I know, it just wouldn't let me accept it straight away. I had to wait a while. But all done now :)

Answer (score 3):

`$countries` is an array. If you want it to be displayed as a list in your `$body`, you can do:

```
$body = implode(', ', $countries);
```

Please also try not to suppress (`@`) PHP errors, it'll cause you more headaches in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jquery, try using **.serializeArray()** instead of stringify.

Also, when receiving the $_POST['contries'] variables, you need to implode it. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit-button").click(function(){
        var countryArray = ['Location Zero', 'Location One', 'Location Two'];
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sendmail.php",
            data: {countries: countryArray.serializeArray()},
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#errors").text("Thank you for getting in touch, we will get back to you!");
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                $("#errors").text("Error sending email, please try again.");
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And then in PHP use this to properly grab the countries values:

```
implode(', '.$countries);
```