# When printing an array, how do you remove the annoying "Array ( )"

Tags: php, arrays

Currently, I have an array, but when I print it using print_r it comes out something like:

```html
Array (

[0] mouse

[1] cat

[2] dog

}
```

My question is, is it possible to ONLY print out the array contents, and not the "Array ( )" in there?

Comment: You mean, you need the index too or just the values in array?

Comment: the index if possible, it's not that big of a deal if the index isn't there but it's very useful in my situation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854520/implode-a-column-of-values-from-a-two-dimensional-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways like this:

**Simple foreach**

```
$arr = ['mouse', 'cat', 'dog'];

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo "[$key] $value<br/>";
}
```

---

**Using [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php):**

```
array_walk($arr,function($value,$key){
    echo "[$key] $value<br/>";
});
```

---

Result:

```
[0] mouse
[1] cat
[2] dog
```

---

Incase you needn't any index, just want to print the values:

```
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    echo "$value<br/>";
}
```

---

**Using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)**

```
array_map(function($value){
    echo "$value<br/>";
}, $arr);
```

---

Results:

```
mouse
cat
dog
```

---

You can use **[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)** to join the array values and print as a string:

```
echo implode(",", $arr);
```

You can also use **[join](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php)** which is alias of implode:

```
echo join(",", $arr);
```

prints:

```
mouse,cat,dog
```

---

You can also use **[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)** format to convert your array to JSON

```
echo json_encode($arr);
```

prints:

```
["mouse","cat","dog"]
```

(credits: @[here2Help](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5970634/here2help))

Comment: I'd add `json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` to the list. I appreciate how I can so easily view the data with just the minimal structure.

Comment: @Here2Help Thanks! Added

Answer (score 0):

Try using `foreach` loop. This will eliminate the `Array` and display your wanted output.

```
<?php

$foo = array('mouse', 'cat', 'dog');

foreach ($foo as $key => $value) {
echo "[$key] $value ";
}

?>
```

**output:**

> [0] mouse [1] cat [2] dog