# Populate option tags with data- attributes using a multidimensional array

Tags: php, json, foreach, html-select, array-column

I have a json file that looks something like this:

```
{
    "world": {
        "france": {
            "city": {
                "city_1": {
                    "name": "paris",
                    "titre": "lorem ipsum"
                },
                "city_2": {
                    "name": "marseille",
                    "titre": "dolor sit amet"
                }
            }
        },
        "usa": {
            "city": {
                "city_1": {
                    "name": "new york",
                    "titre": "lorem ipsum"
                },
                "city_2": {
                    "name": "los angeles",
                    "titre": "lorem ipsum"
                },
                "city_3": {
                    "name": "portland",
                    "titre": "lorem ipsum"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to display a set of option tags with countries as text and some additional attribute declarations like this:

```
<option value="france" data-city="paris,marseille">france</option>
<option value="usa" data-city="new york,los angeles,portland">usa</option>
```

I tried something like this to display the countries, but I can't display the list of cities.

```
foreach ($data['world'] as $key => $value)
{
    $scenario .= '<option value="' . $key . ' data-city="">' . $key .'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cities are in a sub array so you need to do a second loop within your existing foreach to iterate over the cities.

You can create a new array to capture the individual city names in the sub-loop, and then `implode()` them in your `<option>`:

```
$cityArray = array();
foreach($values['city'] as $cityKey=>$cityValue) {
    $cityArray[] = $cityValue['name'];
}

$scenario .= '<option value="' . $key . ' data-city="'.implode(',',$cityArray).'">' . $key .'</option>';
```

Here's a working example: https://3v4l.org/l986m

Answer (score 0):

Extract the `name` elements from the `city` and `implode` them:

```
foreach ($data['world'] as $key => $value)
{
    $cities = implode(',', array_column($value['city'], 'name'));
    $scenario .= '<option value="' . $key . '" data-city="' . $cities . '">' . $key .'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There is never any benefit to duplicating the option's text as its `value` attribute.  All form submission payloads and javascript processes will all work seamlessly without the `value` attributes. These declarations can be safely removed from all option tags that you are populating.
2. By using "array destructuring" syntax in your `foreach()`, you can swiftly and concisely access columns of city data with `array_column()` then `implode()` with commas.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Vdc2R))

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$options = [];
foreach ($data['world'] as $country => ['city' => $cities]) {
    $options[] = sprintf(
        '<option data-city="%s">%s</option>',
        implode(',', array_column($cities, 'name')),
        $country
    );
}

echo implode("\n", $options);
```

Output:

```
<option data-city="paris,marseille">france</option>
<option data-city="new york,los angeles,portland">usa</option>
```

This question is essentially a convoluted way of asking [Implode a column of values from a two dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4854520/2943403)